# JQuery GET request returns whole ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm having an issue with ajax get request. I have searched but I didn't find anything related to ajax get error but about POST request. My issue is that when I call webmethod in asp.net through `ajax` GET request, response contains whole page instead of required response. I also used break point in visual studio to see if the function is getting fired or not. It's not.when I use POST request through `ajax` it works fine.

My `javascript` code:

```
$('#count').click(function () {
    alert("button clicked");

    $.ajax({

        url: "WebForm1.aspx/Count",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "text",                     
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });

});
```

`Asp.Net` code

```
public static int Count()
    {
        int length = messages.Count;
        return length;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3953479)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use HttpGet, you will need `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]`. In addition, the code is missing few Ajax settings - `type: "GET"` *(instead of `method`)* and `contentType: "application/json"`.

```
<button id="count" type="button">Count</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#count').click(function () {
        alert("button clicked");

        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebForm1.aspx/Count") %>',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.d);
            }
        });

    });
</script>

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static int Count()
{
    return 123;
}
```

***FYI:*** We don't normally set `dataType: "text"`; instead, we just accept it as Json, and retrieve the return data as `response.d`.

Comment: except `ResolveUrl` method whole code works fine, so i ran code without it and response came as expected. thanks win.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net in place of `return count;` use `return Json(new {length= message.count});`

And in Js on place of `alert(response)` use `alert(response.length)`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: this will help after the method has fired but in my problem "method is not firing".

Answer (score 0):

You try to reach a method in page class but in asp.net webform you can use generic handlers or webmethods for ajax calls.

Handler Example

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        //do something
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and  in ajax

```
url: "Handler url"
```